# How to export a single feature (line) from multiple layers and export to individual layers?

Tags: qgis, vector, line, clip, select

I have multiple vector layers representing a time series. Each layer contains many lines each. I want to select a single specific line from each of these these layers and save it to another layer. This line represents the same feature (coastline) in every layer but it's position changes over time.

I can certainly do it 1 by 1 using "export - save selected features as...", but that would take forever. Also, I can't highlight all 40+ layers and use "Select Features by area" tool...

This is what 1 layer looks like:

[image]

This is all the layers with the info I want!

[image]

Comment: You could `select by expression` only the longest line of each layer and export it. Should be managable via the model builder.

Comment: Does this same line in all layers have a common attribute? If so, you could create a model using a selection tool such as `Select by attribute` and then use the `Save selected features`. Then run this model as a batch process on all your layers.

Comment: It IS the longest line, I will try this

Comment: Or you could merge the line layers into one layer, then remove all lines shorter than X, where X is the length of the shortest coastline.