# How can I export selected features in Processing Modeler?

Tags: qgis, vector, batch

This question is a follow up from a suggestion from this thread:

[How to export a single feature (line) from multiple layers and export to individual layers?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/309131/how-to-export-a-single-feature-line-from-multiple-layers-and-export-to-individ)

I'm creating a batch process that selects a line (feature) from a vector layer and saves the selected feature to a child layer containing the name of the parent.

I'm using `$length = maximum($length, group_by:= "id")` as the expression because I want to select the longest line in each layer.

The question is how do I export only selected features in the Processing Modeler? I can't find a "Export - Save Selected Features As..." option.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Could `extract by expression` help you? Can't test right now.

Comment: I'm already using that:

$length = maximum($length, group_by:= "id")

Comment: What happens when you save the generated output? Also, you use "select" instead of "extract"

Comment: That's the problem. I want to save the generated output INSIDE the batch modeler. I have over 40 layers and doing it manually is going to take a very long time.

Comment: Did you define your output as final? If so, names should be easily generated when running the model as a batch process.

Comment: As far as I know, extract by expression should work as it's a tool that works exactly like select by expression but has the ability to write a file as output. If the processing model is more complex and this wouldn't work, can you show the workflow?

Comment: Inside the modeler, you can define a named output. When Run, you can define to write the named output to a file (instead a temporary file) and load it to the canvas or not.

Comment: By the way, instead of posting a new question, this could very much have been appended to the original question as it concerns the same task.

Comment: It worked! Thanks guys. By the way I was explicitly told in another thread to post following problems in a new question and not in the same one. Cheers

Comment: @AndreSilva, thank you for your work. I can't know how Steffan solved his issue, but I propose the solution of extracting the features, naming the output and saving it when running the model.

Answer (score 1):

To export features from expression in the modeler, first you need to [Extract features by expression](https://docs.qgis.org/testing/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/qgis/vectorselection.html#extract-by-expression) instead of select them.

In the modeler algorithm, you can define a named output.

> Output generated by an algorithm are handled a bit differently when the algorithm is used as a part of a model. Instead of selecting the filepath where you want to save each output, you just have to specify if that ouput is an intermediate layer (and you do not want it to be preserved after the model has been executed), or it is a final one.
>
> When layers are not a final result, you should just leave the corresponding field. Otherwise, you have to enter a name that will be used to identify the layer in the parameters dialog that will be shown when you run the model later.

Source: https://docs.qgis.org/testing/en/docs/training_manual/processing/modeler_twi.html#starting-with-the-graphical-modeler

When you run the model, you can define to write the named output to a file (instead a temporary file) and load it to the canvas or not.